# Probabilities regarding balls in 13 baskets

Tags: probability

> Consider 13 identical baskets each with a ball or not in itself. Given the first 8 contain 1 in total and the last 8 contain 2 in total, what is the probability that you can find a ball in basket No. **1**, No. **6**, or No. **9**?

Here is my approach:
There are two cases here, let's just denote them as $A$ and $B$, where $A$ refers to that in total there are 2 balls (you can find 1 ball in No.6-No.8 in total), and $B$ represents that in total there are 3 balls (you can find no balls at all in No.6-No.8). Let the probability of $A$ and $B$ to be $p$ and $1-p$, repectively.

In addition, assume the probability of find a ball in basket No. **1-5**, No. **6-8**, or No. **9-13** to be $p_1$,$p_2$,$p_3$. Then obviously we have:
$$5p_1+3p_2=1, 5p_3+3p_2 = 2$$

Using conditional probability, we also have:
$$p_1=0p+\frac{1}{5}(1-p), p_2=\frac{1}{3}p+0(1-p), p_3=\frac{1}{5}p+\frac{2}{5}(1-p)$$

What's more, we know $p = (1-p_2)^3$, since it is only because you find no balls in each basket No. 6-8 can case $A$ happen.

In theory I can solve for $p_2$ using these equations:

$$p_2=\frac{1}{3}(1-p_2)^3\,,$$ which gives me $p_2=0,3$.

What is wrong with my deduction?

Comment: How do you arrive at $5p_3+3p_2 = 2$?  By linearity of expectation, $5p_1+ 5p_3+3p_2 = 2$

Comment: You ask about probabilities, but you haven't introduced any distribution. Are you considering the $2^{13}$ states of $13$ baskets with or without ball as initially equiprobable and then imposing the conditions?

Comment: @joriki Yes sure, I would say that the set-up is to pick up 1 ball and randomly place it in a basket out of the first 8 and do the same thing to the last 8 baskets, only with 2 balls in this case.

Comment: @cxz: Those two statements are incompatible. What I described and what you described yield different distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation $p=(1-p_2)^3$ is incorrect.  The multiplication principle requires that the events are independent.  Here they are not.  You know there is at most one ball in $6-8$.  This means that balls in $6-8$ are mutually exclusive, so $p=3p_2$.  There is a negation error in the setting as well.  $p$ is the probability of one ball in $6-8$, not no balls in $6-8$

Comment: Oh yes, thank you very much sir!

Comment: So, sir, how do I solve the problem? Is it legal to count the possible cases out there and just calculate the proportions of the three events respectively? Because now with the additional information, I don't think every possible event has an equal probability.

Comment: Yes sure I can do that, which is just how the conditional probability works. I am a little stumbled on this.

Comment: Christian Blattner has done a nice analysis for one way of choosing the distribution of the balls.

Answer (score 2):

There has to be an a priori probabilistic model for this game. My model is the following: There is a certain basic probability $p\in\>]0,1[\>$, and each of the $13$ baskets receives a ball with probability $p$, independently of each other. In this way the balls are binomially distributed in the baskets.

We have three groups of baskets, namely $G_1=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, $\>G_2=\{6,7,8\}$, $\>G_3=\{9,10,11,12,13\}$. In the story it is told that $G_1\cup G_2$ contains one ball, and $G_2\cup G_3$ contains two balls. There are then the following possible numbers of balls in the three groups:
$$A:\quad(0,1,1),\qquad B:\quad(1,0,2)\ .$$
The a-priori probabilities of these two cases are
$$\eqalign{P(A)&=(1-p)^5\cdot 3p(1-p)^2\cdot 5p(1-p)^4=15p^2(1-p)^{11},\cr
P(B)&=5p(1-p)^4\cdot(1-p)^3\cdot 10p^2(1-p)^3=50p^3(1-p)^{10}\ ,\cr}$$
so that
$$P(A)+P(B)=(15p^2+35p^3)(1-p)^{10}\ .$$
Therefore the conditional probabilities of $A$ and $B$ are
$$P_A={15p^2(1-p)\over15p^2+35p^3},\qquad P_B={50p^3\over15p^2+35p^3}\ .$$
The probability that you find a ball in basket $1$ then is $$P_1={1\over5}P_B\ ,$$ and the probability that you find a ball in basket $6$ is $$P_6={1\over3}P_A\ .$$ Finally the probability that you find a ball in basket $9$ is
$$P_9={1\over5}P_A+{2\over5}P_B\ .$$